# duplicate component onclick React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, redux-toolkit

I"m new to react, I'm creating a registration from. I want the user to be able to click a button to add an additional person to the registration. I have a "person" component which holds the form fields, onclick I want to duplicate that component.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import Person from './Person'

function BookingForm() {
    const registrationForm = useRef()
    console.log(registrationForm.current)
    let handleAddPerson = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        registrationForm.appendChild(<Person/>)
    }
    
    return (
        <>
        <form ref={registrationForm} id='registrationForm'>
            <Person/>
            <button onClick={handleAddPerson}  className="btn btn-main mt-2"><i className="fas fa-plus"></i> ADD PERSON</button>
        </form>
        </>
    )
}

export default BookingForm
```

Comment: Can you share the `person` component code !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would like to recommend you implement it using `state` instead of `ref`. Like below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Person from './Person'

function BookingForm() {
    const [persons,setPerson] = useState([<Person key={0} />]);

    let handleAddPerson = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setPerson([...persons,<Person key={persons.length} />]);
    }
    
    return (
        <>
        <form id='registrationForm'>
            {persons}
            <button onClick={handleAddPerson}  className="btn btn-main mt-2"><i className="fas fa-plus"></i> ADD PERSON</button>
        </form>
        </>
    )
}

export default BookingForm;
```

Hope this will help you. Using state is better in this case.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking.